# Save Complete Website - Background Images not showing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I click Save As in Firefox, Chrome, or IE, then choose "Webpage, Complete" from the save as menu, it does not appear to be saving the background images defined in my CSS. Am I doing something wrong? Here is a sample problem:

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

test.css

```
#test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url(img/bg.jpg)
}
```

Comment: FWIW, Firefox’s bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115107

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default browsers won't download images set in css.
You can do this in Firefox:
`Right click -> View page info -> select media tab -> highlight all the files -> save as...`

Comment: Not a complete solution - this does save all the images, but the references to those files are still broken.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've been testing saving the complete HTML web page with background images across various browsers and only **Opera 12** was able to save the complete website as seen online. Just open the desired website, click *Ctrl+S* and choose to save a complete website.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. What is saved by Opera 27 appears just as broken as what is saved by Firefox 36, Chrome 40, and MSIE 11.

Comment: I was referring to the classic Opera 12.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution who worked for me is to save the page as MHT with the plugin unMHT (for firefox) :
https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/unmht/

Even webfonts are dowloaded !!

MHT can be opened in IE & Chrome (and firefox but only with this extention).
I know this solution is not perfect but this is the better I found...

Answer (score 1):

in firefox change browser setting:
in URL Type about:config, then enter
search for *browser. download. save_converter_index* and change it to 0

notes
***browser. download. save_converter_index***
The format to save web pages in
0: Web Page (Complete)
1: Web Page (HTML Only)
2: Text